# how can I store my data in a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$(function(){

    var astronautsData;

    $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', doSomething);

    function doSomething(data) {
        astronautsData = data;
    }

    alert(astronautsData.people[0].name)

});
```

I would like to be able to use the data in every function I make, that's why I tried to put it in the variable astronautsData, but unfortunately astronautsdata is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you must understand one thing that getJSON is 'async'. Your alert method trying to show the data which gonna come in future. In order to solve this problem, you must use 'then', 'done' or 'fail' like below.

```js
$(function(){


  var astronautsData;

  //Assign your getjson request
  var jsonRequest = $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json');

  //This function runs once the getJSON method is success
  jsonRequest.done(function(data){
    astronautsData = data;
  });

   //This function runs after the success of getJSON
  jsonRequest.then(function(){
      //Here you have to do your alert ( This alert will give data )
      alert(astronautsData);
  });

  //This alert will give undefined value as this line of code and getjson request runs parallelly
  alert(astronautsData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access astronautsData  inside doSomething.your alert() will get executed 
before getJSON. that's why you are getting undefined.

```
$(function(){

  var astronautsData;

  $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', doSomething);

  function doSomething(data) {
    astronautsData = data;
    alert(astronautsData.people[0].name)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.getJSON` is asynchronous.

Try using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to wait for your call to be done :

```
prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', function(){
    astronautsData = data;
    resolve('Ajax done');
  });
});

prom.then((successMessage) => {
  console.log(successMessage);
  alert(astronautsData.people[0].name)
});
```

Comment: I did that, but it's still not responding.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'people' of undefined

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll have a look at promise to see if this solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Exposing variables in window/global scope is bad in my opinion. You should wrap it in a function (like a class of sorts) and expose it like this:

```
function Values(type) {
    this.value1 = "something";
}
```

From this point you can use prototype to define additional functions on "Values" like so:

```
Values.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    return this.value1 + ' addsomething';
};
```

Inside of the prototype function you can define/return promises or do whatever you want including assigning values to the instance. You can also assign the instance to a global variable to make it a singleton of sorts. Granted your still using a global variable for that but its the instance of Values assigned to the variable not the actual values that are stored.

This is a bit of an over simplification perhaps, but in a way this is how the global variables for lodash or jquery work, although they have a LOT more going on to check for existing global variables and such before attempting to define it on global scope as typically you want to avoid that.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but this went way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

you can use var at global scope (outside of all functions) to declare a global variable:

```
<script>

var astronautsData;
$(function(){


    $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', doSomething);

    function doSomething(data) {
        astronautsData = data;
    }

    alert(astronautsData.people[0].name)

});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

use global.astronautsData if you want it to be global